# How to populate table with json data using angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have loaded the json data successfully via http but having a problem populating a table with this json data based on the entered value 'name'.  Plunker Below.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p7hUWfT6dIfYlDKYo5AF?p=preview)

**json**

```
   [
    {
        "name": "Tim",
        "address": "Road",
        "phone": "1234",
        "status": "busy"
    },

    {
        "name": "Sue",
        "address": "Street",
        "phone": "4321",
        "status": "available"
    }
  ]
```

Assuming my controller and app are defined correctly what am I doing wrong?  I want to type Tim or type Sue and populate the table with corresponding data.

**angular.js**

```
 $http.get('data.json').
     success(function(data) {
      $scope.jsonData = data;
        alert("Success");
     }).
     error(function(data) {
        alert("Invalid URL");
   });

   $scope.clickButton = function(enteredValue) {

    $scope.items = $scope.jsonData;

    angular.forEach($scope.items[enteredValue], function (item, key) {
        $scope.results.push({
                 name: enteredValue,
                 address: item.address,
                 phone: item.phone, 
                 status: item.status
             });

 });
```

**jsp**

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name:</label></td>
  <td>
    <input id="pName" name="pName" type="text" data-ng-model="enteredValue" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click='clickButton(enteredValue)'>Search</button>


 <table>
       <tr data-ng-repeat="result in results">
        <td data-title="'ID'">{{result.status}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Name'">{{result.name}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Status'" >{{result.address}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Start Date'" >{{result.phone}}</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, the problem is that in the json file, the enteredValue (someone's name in this case) is not a valid key in the object, so angulars foreach will never execute because your $scope.items[enteredValue] is always undefined:

```
$http.get('data.json')
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.jsonData = data;
    alert("Success");
})
.error(function(data) {
    alert("Invalid URL");
});

$scope.clickButton = function(enteredValue) {

    $scope.items = $scope.jsonData;

    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
        if(item.name === enteredValue){
            $scope.results.push({
                name: enteredValue,
                address: item.address,
                phone: item.phone, 
                status: item.status
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I've updated your plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YRo8SugTDQ54NIvUHDVy